# How to catch chrome's form validation popups

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I am writing protractor tests for my form validation.

I want to test that an chrome validation popup appears when a required filed is not set in the form.

When a filed is not set i get "Please fill out this field" from chrome.

I want to do something like this :

```
submitBtn = element(by.id('submitBtn'));
submitBtn.click();
validationMessage = ???
expect((validationMessage ).getText()).toBe('Please fill out this field');
```

How to get it ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to test the internal implementations of Chrome. The Chrome developers would have had tests to cover the hiding and showing of popups.

You test that your form is written correctly by finding the element that the `required` attribute should be set on, and asserting that it is indeed set.

```
myInput = element(by.id('myInput'));
expect(myInput.getAttribute('required')).toBeDefined();
```

Comment: Does the `required` attribute only appear after clicking on submit?

Comment: no, unless you specifically have logic to intercept the form submission and add the attribute. Typically you write the HTML with the attribute already included, i.e. `<input type="text" required>` or in the case of Angular `<input type="text" ng-required="...">`. In the Angular case you want to be testing for the existence of the `ng-required` attribute rather than the plain `required` attribute.

Comment: I still want to know how to catch it. I want to test the user experience which includes the chrome messages. I am sure there is a way.